# T-SQL XML : how to update value in one node if there are more nodes with identical names?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2017

I'm just starting to learn how to work with XML data format and I've already got stuck on updating some data. I would really, really appreciate some help with the issue 'cause i have absolutely no idea how to deal with such problem.

Code to generate some sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_iD('tempdb..#beforeXML') is NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #beforeXML 

CREATE TABLE #beforeXML 
(
    ID int NOT NULL,    
    SomeXMLData XML NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #beforeXML (ID, SomeXMLData)
VALUES 
    (1, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 4</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
    (2, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 4, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
    (3, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>false</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 6</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A, C</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
    (4, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
    (5, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>B</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter></Parameters>')

SELECT * FROM #beforeXML
```

Now comes the hard part...

I need to update "Value" node's value where "Key" node's value = "ABC" within the same "Parameter" node.

As you can see I have several "Parameter" nodes inside my xml, these nodes don't have specific order or attributes I could use to distinguish them and determine which ones should I update. There are some rows that don't have such node, and there are some rows that already have digits 3 or/and 5 inside "Value" node, so I need to add only in case one or both (3 or/and 5) is missing.

The result I would like to obtain:

```
IF OBJECT_iD('tempdb..#afterXML') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #afterXML 

CREATE TABLE #afterXML 
(
    ID int NOT NULL,    
    SomeXMLData XML NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #afterXML (ID, SomeXMLData)
VALUES 
    -- added both 3, 5
    (1, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 4, 5</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),  
    -- added only 3
    (2, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter>
<Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 4, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),    
    -- added only 5
    (3, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>false</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 5, 6</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A, C</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
    -- no change
    (4, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'), 
    -- no change
    (5, '<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>B</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter></Parameters>')  

SELECT * FROM #afterXML
```

I've managed to extract values from that particular "Value" node for each row, check what digits are missing and prepare data for update

So I have `temp_table` with data like this:

```
IF OBJECT_iD('tempdb..#temp_table') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #temp_table

CREATE TABLE #temp_table 
(
    ID int NOT NULL,    
    NewSetOfValues varchar(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #temp_table (ID, NewSetOfValues)
VALUES 
    (1, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'),
    (2, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'),
    (3, '1, 2, 3, 5, 6')
 
SELECT * FROM #temp_table
```

but that's where I've got stuck.

I have absolutely no idea how to construct proper modify method syntax to update only specific "Value" node within presented xml structure... :(

Is there some easy way to deal with such update?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, this does not sort the XML string in order of number, but you should be able to work it in to how you need it:

```sql
update b
-- .modify is a special function that modifies XML in place
set SomeXMLData.modify('
    replace value of
    (/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value/text())[1]
    with
    concat (
        (/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value/text())[1],
        if ((/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value[contains(text()[1], "3")])[1] ) then "" else ", 3" ,
        if ((/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value[contains(text()[1], "5")])[1] ) then "" else ", 5" 
    )')
from @beforeXML b;
```

The way this works is as follows:

1. We search for XML nodes, starting at root `/`, descending `Parameters`, then `Parameter` but this node must have a sub-node `Key` which has a `text()="ABC"`, then descend `/Value/text())` and take the first `[1]` node.
2. Replace this value with the concatenation of the existing value, and:
3. if `Value` node matches `[contains(text()[1], "3")])[1] )` then nothing, else we add ", 3"
4. if `Value` node matches `[contains(text()[1], "5")])[1] )` then nothing, else we add ", 5"

Result:

```
|SomeDataXML|
----
|<Parameters><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 4, 3, 5</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter></Parameters>|
|<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 4, 5, 3</Value></Parameter></Parameters>|
|<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>false</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 6, 5</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A, C</Value></Parameter></Parameters>|
|<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>|
|<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>B</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter></Parameters>|
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Charlieface, please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali It became one of the most popular requests for SQL Server.
The current voting tally is 511 and counting.

Comment: @Charlieface. 

Thank you very much for your help. That was exactly what I needed in this case.
The sequence of numbers wasn't the main issue, so solution presented by you was sufficient to deal with my data.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of numbers shall be sorted, you can try the following solution. It is using a pair of handy functions available in SQL Server 2017:

- `STRING_SPLIT()`
- `STRING_AGG()`

All credit goes to @Charlieface

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl Table (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SomeXMLData XML NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl (SomeXMLData) VALUES
(N'<Parameters><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 4</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
(N'<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 4, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
(N'<Parameters><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>false</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 6</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A, C</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
(N'<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>A</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>ABC</Key><Value>1, 2, 3, 5</Value></Parameter></Parameters>'),
(N'<Parameters><Parameter><Key>XYZ</Key><Value>B</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Key>KLM</Key><Value>true</Value></Parameter></Parameters>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- concat missing numbers
UPDATE b
SET SomeXMLData.modify('
    replace value of
    (/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value/text())[1]
    with
    concat (
        (/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value/text())[1],
        if ((/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value[contains(text()[1], "3")])[1] ) then "" else ", 3" ,
        if ((/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value[contains(text()[1], "5")])[1] ) then "" else ", 5" 
    )')
FROM @tbl AS b;

-- get sequence of numbers sorted
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , (SELECT STRING_AGG(TRIM(value), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TRIM(value) ASC)
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(SomeXMLData.value('(/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)'), ',')
                ) AS Result
    FROM @tbl
)
UPDATE rs
SET SomeXMLData.modify('
    replace value of
    (/Parameters/Parameter[Key[text()="ABC"]]/Value/text())[1]
    with (sql:column("Result"))');

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Shame you can't do this in XQuery directly, probably would have been more efficient. Personally, I would just select out the existing, add the extra ones and re-aggregate, without the original `UPDATE`

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right on target. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: I think these two are far more important https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145-add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distin and https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32890519-add-a-built-in-table-of-numbers

Comment: @Charlieface Or this one: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889769-suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for

Comment: @Shnugo Not really bothered. How often do I ever construct XML out of SQL, and if I do, I do it client-side. I think the ones I mention are much more pertinent.

Comment: @Charlieface, well, that's a question of your point-of-view :-) However, i hadn't even realized, that ancient Connect-Items where ported to this Azure platform. But something did not change at all: Nothing happens :-) The issue I pointed to is almost 14 years old. Many issues have some antique value already :-) I think, MS is just keeping them for museal reasons...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Since the order of numbers in a sequence wasn't the main issue, I makred Charlieface's solution as "Accepted". However you have presented very interesting solution to my problem. Surely I will need to sort my data at some point in a future and solution presented by you worked perfectly.  

Sorry guys, I took me so long to respond. Thank you again :)

Comment: @alice_ef, glad to hear that you recognized techniques and value that my solution is bringing to the table. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali